# vb 2005 direct memory access

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, memory

I want to know if I can directly read or write values in the current process in a Visual Basic 2005 Windows application.

Like `*(DWORD*)(0x123456) = 1;` in C++ will write the value 1 at the address 0x123456.

So anyway to do the same in VB using only built in functions and not using ReadProcessMemory and WriteProcessMemory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are really sure you need to do this you should look into the [Marshal Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), specifically `Marshal.WriteByte`.

But I am pretty sure `Marshal` makes heavy use of Win32 API functions so it's questionable if it's really "built in".

Comment: thank you for your answer. that's what i needed although it doesnt write single or double but its ok                                                                    edit : found it :)